# Преобразовать одно представление дерева в другое

Tags: mongodb, дерево, firebase

В mongodb содержатся данные с полями `[_id, parentId]`.
Как преобразовать эту структуру в формат с `children ids`, используемый [firebase](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html):

```
{
  123: {
    _id: 123,
    children: [
      325: true,
      155: true,
      // ...
    ]
  },
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Моё решение (coffeescript, mongodb, nodejs, asyncjs):

```
async = require 'async'
fs = require 'fs'

class FirebaseConverter
  constructor: (@_collection) ->

  convert: (done) =>
    async.waterfall [
      (cb) => @_extractAll cb
      (d, cb) => async.map d, @_cleanUp, cb
      (d, cb) => async.map d, @_down, cb
      (d, cb) => async.map d, @_up, cb
      (d, cb) => async.reduce d, {}, @_appendKeys, cb
      (d, cb) => fs.writeFile '../data/firebase.json', JSON.stringify(d), console.log; cb null, d
    ], (e, d) => done null, d

  _appendKeys: (memo, item, cb) ->
    delete item.CategoryParentID
    memo[item.CategoryID] = item
    cb null, memo

  _extractAll: (cb) =>
    @_collection.find().limit(1e5).toArray (e, d) ->
      throw e if e
      cb null, d

  _cleanUp: (item, cb) ->
    console.log "item", item.CategoryID
    result = {}
    result["CategoryID"] = item.CategoryID
    result["CategoryName"] = item.CategoryName
    result["CategoryParentID"] = item.CategoryParentID
    cb null, result

  _up: (item, cb, parentId) =>
    if 'up' not of item
      item["up"] = []
    query = { CategoryID: parentId or item.CategoryParentID }
    @_collection.find(query).toArray (error, parent) =>
      parent = parent[0]
      if item.CategoryID isnt parent.CategoryID  # not self reference
        parentObject = { "CategoryID": parent.CategoryID, "CategoryName": parent.CategoryName }
#        console.log parentObject, parent
        item["up"].unshift parentObject
      if parent.CategoryID isnt parent.CategoryParentID  # not top level
        @_up item, cb, parent.CategoryParentID
      else
        cb null, item

  _down: (item, cb) =>
    query = { CategoryParentID: item.CategoryID }
    @_collection.find(query).toArray (error, subQuery) ->
      item["down"] = []
      for child in subQuery
        continue if child.CategoryID is child.CategoryParentID
        childObject = { "CategoryID": child.CategoryID, "CategoryName": child.CategoryName }
        item["down"].push childObject
      cb null, item
```

Результат:

```
{"CategoryID":"99","CategoryName":"Everything Else","down":[{"CategoryID":"319","CategoryName":"Adult Only"},{"CategoryID":"3143","CategoryName":"Career Development & Education"},{"CategoryID":"177600","CategoryName":"eBay Special Offers"},{"CategoryID":"20924","CategoryName":"eBay User Tools"},{"CategoryID":"88739","CategoryName":"Funeral & Cemetery"},{"CategoryID":"20925","CategoryName":"Genealogy"},{"CategoryID":"102480","CategoryName":"Information Products"},{"CategoryID":"19266","CategoryName":"Metaphysical"},{"CategoryID":"102329","CategoryName":"Personal Development"},{"CategoryID":"102535","CategoryName":"Personal Security"},{"CategoryID":"102553","CategoryName":"Reward Points & Incentives"},{"CategoryID":"88433","CategoryName":"Every Other Thing"},{"CategoryID":"102545","CategoryName":"Religious Products & Supplies"},{"CategoryID":"1466","CategoryName":"Weird Stuff"},{"CategoryID":"14112","CategoryName":"Test Auctions"}]}
```